# delay on an event, such as change background color of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to use the `<delay>` for the delay of the event, such as change the background color. I want the event to follow the delay time I want, but the result shows me that they are not in the order I want. I am expecting the first one become red in 1 second. Then the second one become red in 2 seconds. Then the third one become red in 0.8 seconds. And I don't know how to make them the different color.
Thank you very much for the help.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var delayTime = [1000, 2000, 800];
    var bcolor = ['red','blue','green'];
    var i = 0;
    $('#play').click(function(){
        $('div').each(function(){
            $(this).delay(delayTime[i]).queue( function(next){
                $(this).css('background','red');        
                next();
            });
            i++;
        }); // end of each
    });
 }); // end ready
```

```html
<script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<div id="red" style="width:100px; height: 100px; background-color: white" ></div>
<div id="blue" style="width:100px; height: 100px; background-color: white"></div>
<div id="green" style="width:100px; height: 100px; background-color: white"></div>
<button id="play">Play</button>
<h1 id="test"></h1>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1st:** instead of `i=0;` you can use `index of div`

**2nd:** for delayTime you can add a previous time to the new one to get the right delay time .. So if you have [1000 , 2000 , 800]  the new delay time will be 1000 then 3000 then 3800 and so on

you can use this code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var delayTime = [1000, 2000, 800];
    var bcolor = ['red','blue','green'];
    var timeDelay = 0;
    $('#play').click(function(){
        $('div').each(function(i){  // i mean index of div starts from 0
            timeDelay += delayTime[i]; // add a pervious delayTime (the trick here)
            $(this).delay(timeDelay).queue( function(){
                $(this).css('background', bcolor[i]); //use bcolor[i] to get a color
            });
        }); // end of each
    });
 }); // end ready
```

```html
<script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<div id="red" style="width:100px; height: 100px; background-color: white" ></div>
<div id="blue" style="width:100px; height: 100px; background-color: white"></div>
<div id="green" style="width:100px; height: 100px; background-color: white"></div>
<button id="play">Play</button>
<h1 id="test"></h1>
```

Answer (score 2):

You also need to use the loop to pick up colors:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var delayTime = [1000, 2000, 800];
  var bcolor = ['red', 'blue', 'green'];
  var i = 0;
  $('#play').click(function() {
    $('div').each(function() {
      var bg = bcolor[i]; // here update value color
      $(this).delay(delayTime[i]).queue(function(next) {

        $(this).css('background', bg);
        next();
      });
      i++;
    }); // end of each
  });
}); // end ready
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="red" style="width:100px; height: 30px; background-color: white"></div>
<div id="blue" style="width:100px; height: 30px; background-color: white"></div>
<div id="green" style="width:100px; height: 30px; background-color: white"></div>
<button id="play">Play</button>
<h1 id="test"></h1>
```

Answer (score -2):

I am not so into jQuery but I can see that you have fixed color value on the following line:

```
$(this).css('background','red');
```

Maybe that is causing the problem?

Comment: duplicates @GCyrillus answer in essence