# Kivy - How to set duration for a piece of code?

Tags: python, button, kivy, duration, kivy-language

I have:

```
Button:
    text: "SEQUENCE 2"
    size_hint: None, .16
    width: 225
    on_press:
        self.background_color = (1.7, 0, 1.7, 1)
```

which I'd like the 'self.background_color' to switch back to normal (what it was before press) a certain amount of seconds after 'on_press'.

How would I go about doing this?

EDIT (Within the .kv StackLayout is the desired location.)

```
<ContScreen>:
    StackLayout
        orientation: "tb-rl"
        spacing: 15

        Button:
            text: "SEQUENCE 1"
            size_hint: None, .16
            width: 225

        Button:
            text: "SEQUENCE 2"
            size_hint: None, .16
            width: 225
```

If it isn't possible to integrate in the .kv StackLayout, how can I reformat it to work based on the '<>' method.

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37225206/delay-on-an-event-such-as-change-background-color-of-div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use [Clock.create_trigger()](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.clock.html#triggered-events) to create a trigger event.
2. When the durations has expired or met, reset the button's [background_color](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.button.html#kivy.uix.button.Button.background_color) to the defaults colour of [1, 1, 1, 1]

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.clock import Clock


class ButtonBackgroundColourDemo(Button):

    def on_press(self):
        print("\non_press")
        self.duration = 5
        self.background_color_event = Clock.create_trigger(self.set_background_colour, 1)
        self.background_color = (1.7, 0, 1.7, 1)
        self.background_color_event()

    def set_background_colour(self, dt):
        print("\tdt=", dt)
        self.duration -= 1
        if self.duration <= 0:
            self.background_color = [1, 1, 1, 1]    # reset to default colour
        else:
            self.background_color_event()


class Test(App):

    def build(self):
        return ButtonBackgroundColourDemo()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Test().run()
```

### test.kv

```
#:kivy 1.11.0

<ButtonBackgroundColourDemo>:
    text: "SEQUENCE 2"
    size_hint: None, .16
    width: 225
```

## Output

[image: Img01]
[image: Img02]